Azure AI Search Sharepoint URLs
I am currently indexing Sharepoint Files in Azure via AI Search.
This index is then used in AI Studio via "add your data". This way the Sharepoint documents are used as citations in the chat, but I am unable to retrieve URLs to the used citations.
The closes I am getting to an url is via the metadata field "metadata_spo_item_path" which returns some url matching the following template "/drives/b![hexadecimalString]/root:/[documentname]".
My problem is:

How to make the AI Search not only return relevant document chunks but also the urls to the regarding file?
Can I somehow translate the path provided by "metadata_spo_item_path" to a clickable URL?

I tried using AI Search Index and using the metadata filed metadata_spo_item_path. This however didn't provide an URL that any user with permissions can click onto to get redirected to the regarding file.

According to this documentation when you are indexing document metadata you will get the following metadata.
metadata_spo_site_library_item_id,
metadata_spo_site_id,
metadata_spo_library_id,
metadata_spo_item_id,
metadata_spo_item_last_modified,
metadata_spo_item_name,
metadata_spo_item_size,
metadata_spo_item_content_type,
metadata_spo_item_extension,
metadata_spo_item_weburi,
metadata_spo_item_path
In this you need to use metadata_spo_item_weburi in ai studio chat playground.
So, create a index with metadata_spo_item_weburi  as field, below is the json body to create index.
{
    "name" : "sharepoint-index",
    "fields": [
        { "name": "id", "type": "Edm.String", "key": true, "searchable": false },
        { "name": "metadata_spo_item_name", "type": "Edm.String", "key": false, "searchable": true, "filterable": false, "sortable": false, "facetable": false },
        { "name": "metadata_spo_item_path", "type": "Edm.String", "key": false, "searchable": false, "filterable": false, "sortable": false, "facetable": false },
        { "name": "metadata_spo_item_content_type", "type": "Edm.String", "key": false, "searchable": false, "filterable": true, "sortable": false, "facetable": true },
        { "name": "metadata_spo_item_last_modified", "type": "Edm.DateTimeOffset", "key": false, "searchable": false, "filterable": false, "sortable": true, "facetable": false },
        { "name": "metadata_spo_item_size", "type": "Edm.Int64", "key": false, "searchable": false, "filterable": false, "sortable": false, "facetable": false },
        { "name": "content", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "filterable": false, "sortable": false, "facetable": false },
        { "name": "metadata_spo_item_weburi", "type": "Edm.String", "key": false, "searchable": false, "filterable": false, "sortable": false, "facetable": false }
    ]
}

Next, when you are adding data source in chat playground,

check mark Use custom field mapping and click on next.
In Data field mapping select File name or URL as  metadata_spo_item_weburi.

Now, you are able to get the relevant link when you do query.
